# Visual Studio 2012 "Apply Code Changes" menu-item is missing for native C++ debugging (probably due to managed-code projects in solution)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, native, edit-and-continue

I suspect that this relates to having managed-code DLL projects in the solution, since in VS2010 the menu-item was also missing unless I manually unloaded all managed-code projects from the solution.

In VS2012 though, I now have many more managed DLLs in the solution (not by personal choice), so I am hoping that there might be a way to enable "Apply Code Changes" even with managed DLLs in the solution.

I have set my local debugging mode to "Native Only" and also edited the "Edit and Continue" options under Debug - Options and Settings... to enable native "Edit and Continue", but still I get no "Apply Code Changes" icon under the Debug menu.

If I manually add the 'Apply Code Changes' button to a toolbar, it remains continually disabled.

Please can anyone offer any hints and tips as to how I might get this to work, or do I simply have to unload all managed-code projects from the solution?

Supposing that I do have to unload the managed-code projects, is there a straightforward way to maintain two different sets of solution options so that I can quickly decide whether I wish to mount all projects or native-only?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not have a definitive solution to your problem (I am an a similar position myself) I suspect that a good thorough reading of this MSDN document would be productive for us both:

[Edit and Continue (Visual C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @James - I gave up in the end, having discovered that with edit and continue enabled, the custom visualizers didn't work for debugging.  I'm just having to get used to the kill, rebuild and try again cycle.  At this point I'm fed up of VS2012!